# Google Drive Push notification for android is it works with appengine as domain

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Is it possible that  push notification on Android of  google drive works 
If I make  AppEngine project which i registered as domain.

code not working

```
      Drive.Changes.List request1 = mService.changes().list(startpageToken);
            ChangeList changes1 = request1.execute();
            Channel channel = new Channel();
            channel.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            channel.setType("web_hook");
           channel.setAddress("https://ggledrvsrvcaccnt.appspot.com/hello");
            System.out.println(" **channel 
                      Id"+channel.getId()+"paggtoken"+startpageToken);
            Channel c = mService.changes().watch(startpageToken, 
           channel).execute();
            System.out.println("ResourceId"+c.getResourceId());
            System.out.println("Kind"+c.getKind());
            System.out.println("resuri"+c.getResourceUri());
            System.out.println("token"+c.getToken());
            System.out.println("expi"+c.getExpiration());
```

output is
     **channel Iddce0eb26-e23d-43f8-a50b-a68aee2aa286paggtoken508
     ResourceId nT5QxvC2hKhVrDdPn61i5H6Jr10
     Kind api#channel
    resuri https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?includeCorpusRemovals=false&includeRemoved=true&includeTeamDriveItems=false&pageSize=100&pageToken=508&restrictToMyDrive=false&spaces=drive&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json

token null
expi 1493122880000

But still not able to get notification on status bar
If i check in api explorer 
All Versions > Drive API v3 > drive.changes.watch

```
 {
 "error": {
 "errors": [
 {
 "domain": "global",
"reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: 
 https://ggledrvsrvcaccnt.appspot.com/hello"
 }
 ],
 "code": 401,
 "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: 
 https://ggledrvsrvcaccnt.appspot.com/hello"
 }
 }
```

Please Let me know Am I on wrong track

For checking Notification that is information in notification
 which event or service to invoke in android code..